# Changing GruntFile does not change the livereload port

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, watch, livereload

I need to run grunt on multiple projects. But it gives the error 'Port 35729 is already in use by another process' on one project which is the livereload port. Even if I change the value to a different port in connect of initConfig of Gruntfile the same error keeps coming up when trying to start the project. What could be reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I have to change the

`livereload:true`

to

`livereload:12345` (the port you need)